# alphavantage bist100 api does not respond

Tags: api, rest, alpha-vantage

I'm trying to retrieve bist100 values using api, but it returns empty.

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=XU100.IS&interval=5min&apikey=MYKEY

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data running this python script.

Make sure you do `pip install alpha_vantage` first

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime as dt
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries


stock_ticker = 'SPY'
api_key = 'yourkey'

ts = TimeSeries (key=api_key, output_format = "pandas")
data_daily, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=stock_ticker, interval ='1min', outputsize ='full')

print(data_daily)
```

[image]